# Part identification (single part)

Tags: part-identification

I'd be grateful if someone could help me identify this part. It's from the Lego Power Functions Ideas book, which has a gallery of required parts, but without part numbers.

[image]

Comment: Why does it say you need zero of that part?

Comment: The photo is from the 2nd book in a set of two by Yoshihito Isogawa. The appendix lists all the parts required for the models in each book, and the required quantity. It also states (in brackets) how many of each part is required for the models in the sister book. I cropped this out unintentionally from the photo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is [4281515: Bionicle Eye](https://brickset.com/parts/4281515/bion-eye).

Appears in 22 sets according to Brickset.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Been trying to find this for days.

Comment: Glad I could help. I've been sorting through Chima stuff recently so recognised it.